# Check my reasoning? (Functions where multiplying the input divides area under the curve by the same factor)

Tags: calculus, functions, solution-verification

One of the ways that you can change a function is by multiplying its input by a constant, $f(x)\rightarrow f(\lambda x)$. This results in the function being horizontally stretched/compressed by that same factor $\lambda$. So I wanted to find all functions where not only the width but also the area shrinks by the factor $\lambda$. This means finding a function which, for $a,b,\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$, satisfies $$\int_a^b{f(\lambda x) dx}=\frac1\lambda \int_a^b{f(x)dx}$$

My argument starts with moving the $1/\lambda$ inside the integral.$$\int_a^b{f(\lambda x) dx}=\int_a^b{\frac1\lambda f(x)dx}$$ Then since the equation should hold no matter the values of $a$ and $b$, the functions must be the same.$$f(\lambda x)=\frac1\lambda f(x)$$ $$\lambda f(\lambda x)=f(x)$$
$$\lambda xf(\lambda x)=xf(x)$$ Now if I let $y=\lambda x$ I get $$yf(y)=xf(x)$$ Since $x$ and $\lambda$ are arbitrary, so is $y$ and $(x,y)$ represents an arbitrary pair of real numbers. This implies the product of the input and output of the function never changes, so
$$xf(x)=C$$ $$f(x)=\frac Cx$$ Are there any other functions that satisfy the conditions, or any holes in my argument?

Comment: Well if this was true, then it implies that $(a,b)$ does not contain $0$. Also the statement of the integrands being the same may require some further justification.